# SQL syntax error near desc

Tags: mysql, sql

The error I get is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Desc) values(1,'Sem 2','1',1,'1234','2017-11-03','2',3,'vnfhmj.k;/kkc')' at line 1

If I remove `desc...` the error is gone. Is there a limit to number of items which can be entered?

Code:

```
String query="insert into exam(sub_id,exam_sem,co,tch_id,ex_pwd,ex_date,ex_duration,noofq,Desc) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt=DatabaseConnector.getPreparedStatement(query);
//pstmt.setInt(1,ed.getEx_id());
pstmt.setInt(1,ed.getSub_id());
pstmt.setString(2,ed.getEx_sem());
pstmt.setString(3,ed.getEx_co());
pstmt.setInt(4,ed.getT_id());
pstmt.setString(5,ed.getEx_pwd());
pstmt.setString(6,ed.getEx_date());
pstmt.setString(7,ed.getEx_duration());
pstmt.setInt(8,ed.getNoofq());
pstmt.setString(9,ed.getDesc());
```

Answer (score 3):

DESC is an SQL keyword used to specify direction in an ORDER BY clause. That's probably the problem. Try surrounding it in backticks like `Desc`.

Also, try to be careful not to use keywords or SQL functions as field names in the future, it can lead to really difficult to debug errors.

Comment: Correct. You need to escape the column name with backticks! as per @jspurim response

Comment: Yup, now I just need to know how to escape ` in markdown to edit my answer XD.

Comment: Glad, to help. Please consider accepting the answer if it was useful to you.